# Want to know the number of times a value appears on a given date

Tags: php, mysql

I will try to explain this in as simple a way as possible. I want to be able to count how many times a value is entered into my database table for each day.

Basically, if the data is entered once it would count as a single, if the data was entered twice it would count as a double and if the data was entered three times it would count as a treble.

I then want to be able to count how many singles, doubles and trebles appear within a certain time frame (April to April each year). Then of course echo them out on to the php page like so:

Singles - 23
Doubles - 69
Trebles - 3

I tried adding a round_id column in the database table as I thought if that was default 1 and I could somehow count each day how many 1's appeared that would work but I am totally stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please give table layout (`DESCRIBE`) and some example data

Comment: Sorry Kaii I am new to this so just noticed your comment I will try to explain more.

Comment: Sorry Kaii I am new to this so just noticed your comment I will try to explain more.

It is a caddie log that I am building for my work as a caddie. Every day I want to fill in these fields, if I do two rounds I will fill it in twice so I want that to count as a double round.

At the moment the table looks like this although it is not final.

database table:

round
date
round_length
course
additional_caddies
pay
notes
round_id

I have managed to echo out the total rounds which is just the latest 'round' but doing what I want is a little more than my knowledge of php and mysql can stretch too.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, to start, we can get a count by day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, `date`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `date`
```

That will give you the count of records for each day.

Then we can wrap that in another query:

```
SELECT dailycount.daycnt AS `type`, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS daycnt, `date`
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY `date`
) dailycount
WHERE `date` BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
GROUP BY daycnt
```

This will give you something like this:

```
type cnt
1    23
2    69
3    3
```

where `type` would be your singles, doubles, etc.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I am struggling a little here. I could use your first SELECT COUNT to show whether it was a 1, 2 or a 3 for each day. However, when I try to use the second SELECT COUNT it keeps saying "Database query failed: Every derived table must have its own alias". I may need a bit more help with the PHP side of it if you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my query to use an alias on the subquery - that should fix it.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. How do I do this in PHP? I can get the first numbers to show but again there is an error with the second SELECT. How do I echo it out to show as you have below?

Comment: @user1296020 don't say "there is an error". Show the actual error message so others can help you.

Comment: Sorry:

Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `date` BETWEEN start_date AND end_date' at line

Comment: @user1296020 Sorry, I fixed it. MySQL requires that `GROUP BY` comes after `WHERE`...

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that worked although now I get an unknown column error for start_date, should I have start date in my database table? Also, do I do both of those queries or just the second one?

Comment: Just the second one, the first was for demonstration and is included in the second one. You get an error on `start_date` because that isn't a real field. You said you wanted to run this in a certain timeframe, so I was putting the where clause in for you. Replace `start_date` and `end_date` with the dates you want to count.

Comment: Ok I get no database errors now so it is obviously working. My next question is how do I then echo the results out to show on my php page? Forgive my limited knowledge! Thanks for your help so far, much appreciated!

Comment: Using the following code it shows up "Resource id #6" in my browser.

[php]
// Database Query
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT dailycount.daycnt AS `type`, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS daycnt, `date`
    FROM `logbook`
    GROUP BY `date`
) dailycount
WHERE `date` BETWEEN 2012-02-01 AND 2013-02-01
GROUP BY daycnt", $connection);
 
 if (!$result) {
  die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 
 echo $result;[php]

Comment: @user1296020 You need to loop through the resultset, you can't just echo it out. Try reading here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php The example should get you going.

Comment: Tried to understand that Ryan but I just can't. My PHP knowledge hasn't reached that level yet. I don't understand the results of the query so I therefore can't understand how I am supposed to loop them. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure, here's the best SQL I could come out with:
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field) FROM table GROUP BY field`

That will count the number of field appearances for each value.